# how can i bode plot this low pass filter?

Tags: matlab, plot, filter, transform

i am not an expert by any means in matlab but i am asked to plot this transfer function which reflects an active low pass filter but i can't seem to get it right ... can you point out where is the error in this command please? ( the error shows a graph with  straight lines)

```
num=9.18;
den=[(10e3)*(5e-9)];
lowpass= tf(num,den)
bode (lowpass)
```

I think i have missed up with the brackets but can't tell unfortunately, and i know another command which is easier to generate the required graph , but i have been ask to do this one as it shows the correct form of the transform function.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a MATLAB issue. You have defined the transfer function `9.18/(10e3*5e-9)`=`9.18/5.0000e-05`. This results in a transfer function representing a static gain of `183600`. So you defined only one numerator and one denominator coefficient.

You probably mean: `den=[ 10e3, 5e-9 ];` giving you two denominator coefficients.

```
>> lowpass

lowpass =

       9.18
  ---------------
  10000 s + 5e-09

Continuous-time transfer function.
```

This results in lowpass characteristics:

```
bode(lowpass)
```

[image: bode plot of lowpass]